# Package: react-native-push-notification, is it possible to add images to the message show to the user

Tags: react-native, push-notification

For my push notification in react native I use the package, react-native-push-notification.

I want to add an Image to the message property but don`t know if this is possible.
Doe someone have expierence with this package or can someone tell me what I can use to achieve this or if it is even possible.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-firebase or react-native-fcm, both works fine.